# mail attachment SendGrid using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid, cloud9-ide

I am trying to send an email with an attachment in Ruby and I have the following line:

```
from = Email.new(email: 'mail@mail.com')
to = Email.new(email: 'mail@mail.com')
subject = 'file for this week'
content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'Please find file for this week.')
mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)
mail.attachments['test.txt'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/test.txt")
sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key:'myapikey')
sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
```

The issue is code by the following line (when I remove it, I receive an email):

```
mail.attachments['test.txt'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/test.txt")
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

`undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass`

Has anyone faced this error before?

Comment: It means that `mail.attachments` is returning nil. Where is the `mail` variable coming from?

Comment: I have updated the source code in the question.

Comment: Please check again

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail%2Enew), normally you would create a new `Mail` object using a Hash with the values being Strings. It's hard to tell, because I don't know what your `Email` or `Content` classes are doing, but I suspect something is going wrong when you create `mail`. Let's get those unknown classes out of the picture for starters.

Try changing your code to:

```
from = 'mail@mail.com'
to = 'mail@mail.com'
subject = 'file for this week'
content = 'Please find file for this week.'

mail = Mail.new(from: from, to: to, subject: subject, body: content)
mail.attachments['test.txt'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/test.txt")

sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key:'myapikey')
sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
```

Comment: This didn't work either. The example I am using is from here:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby#with-mail-helper-class

Comment: What line is throwing the error? Please include a full stack dump that includes the error.

Comment: the `mail.attachments['test.txt'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/test.txt")` line

Comment: Well that is odd, because I can type all those lines verbatim into Rails console and I get back a Mail object with the attachment on it. Don't know what to tell you. How are you running your code? Have you tried running the Rails console and typing the lines one at a time?